# Font-size jumps to random number above certain value

Tags: css

So i am bulding a responsive website, i made a css file that contains all the style for the home page. I first styled the desktop version and now i am working on the mobile version. All pretty straight forward. Howerver i am running into an issue thats pretty strange. The font size on desktop is set in css, something around 20px, now i want that font size to increse on mobile by putting a @media tag. This @media contains new incresed font-sizes for mobile. everything went fine untill i tried to change the a and p tags. Most of the fonts-sizes increse to the new font size however a few dont, they will change to a random number that is nowere to be found in my stylesheet. So i tought it might be a font size set as a percentage somewhere. To troubleshoot this i tried changing the font-size to 1 px smaller then the desired size. and it changed by a little bit, so i tought i confirmed it whas a percentage somewhere. However i made the font size 3px smaller just to be shure and this time it jumps to the correct font size.

So to summerize i want to set font-size via @media tag. Some of the text on the page changes to a completly random number but when i set it just under a setrain value it jumps back to my desired size.

I allso deleted every font-size tag in my stylesheet and none exept the new one in @media had any effect.

I allso gave the font-size in @media a !important tag

I added notes to the parts that have the problems, both of these parts need a font size of 36 px

```
body{
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0;
}

*{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:#383838;

}



/* navbar */

.topnav {
  background-color: #43B02a;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left:15%;
  padding-right:15%;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}



/* all links */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a i{
  color:white;
}

.el{
  color:white;
}



/* active */

.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: #43B02a;
}

.active:hover{
  color:white;
}



/* hide hamburger */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}



/* dropdown box */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}



/* dropdownbutton */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px; 
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 13px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;

}

bt{
  color:white;
}
bt i{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  color:white;
  transition:0.3s;
}


.dropbtn:hover i{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition:0.4s;
}



/* dropdownlist */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}



/* dropdownlinks */

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}



/* Hover effect */

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3c9e25;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #43B02a;
}



/* dropdnw unhide */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}



/* responsiveness */

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav{
    padding:0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .topnav a, bt{
    font-size:36px;
  }
}

#logbtn{
  float:right;
}

#logbtn lg{
  margin-left:10px;
  color:white;
  transition:0.3s;
}

#logbtn:hover lg{
  margin-left:5px;
  transition:0.7s;
}

#logbtn:hover i{
  margin-left:5px;
  transition:0.7s;
}



/* logobanner */

.logo_container{
  width:100%;
  background-color:white;
}

.logo_container img{
  width:20%;
  height:auto;
  margin:10px;
  margin-left:40%;
  margin-right:40%;
}



/* responsiveness */

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .logo_container img{
  width:40%;
  margin:10px;
  margin-left:30%;
  margin-right:30%;
  }
  #logbtn{
  float:none;
}
  #logbtn i{
    display:none;
  }
}



.typewriter{
  width:100%;
  margin-top:15%;
  float:left;
}

.typewriter_mbl{
  display:none;
  margin-left:2%;
  margin-top:10%;
  font-size:20px;
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:-10%;
}

.typewriter_mbl h1{
  font-weight:400;
  color:white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #383838;
}

.typewriter h1 {
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  max-width:48ch;
  border-right: .15em solid #43B02a; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .10em; 
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
    blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
  float:left;
  color:white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #383838;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0;
         opacity:1;}
  to { width: 100%;
       opacity:1;}
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: #43B02a; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .typewriter{
    display:none;
  }
  .typewriter_mbl{
    display:block;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .typewriter_mbl{
    margin:5%;
    font-size:46px;
  }
}



landing{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-image: url("../img/stock-photo-working-at-home-with-laptop-woman-writing-a-blog-female-hands-on-the-keyboard-370107740.jpg");
  padding-left:15%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float:left;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100%;
  /*background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.81) !important;
  background-blend-mode: color;*/
  background-position: 0 30%; 

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .banner{
  padding-left:2%;

}
}
.boxes{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-bottom:7.5%;
}
  .box{
    width:20.5%;
    margin-right:10%;
    height:50px;
    padding:12.5px;
    padding-right:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
    background-color:rgba(67, 176, 42, 0.7);
    color:white;
     box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }

.box:hover{
     box-shadow: 0 15px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     background-color:rgba(67, 176, 42, 0.95);
     transition:0.3s;
     cursor:pointer;
     padding-right:10px;
  }

.box i{
  float:right;
  font-size:25px;
  color:white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .box{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
    padding-top:25px;
}
  landing{
    padding-left:0%;
  }
  .boxes{
    margin-bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#43B02a;
    padding:5%;
    padding-bottom:2.5%;
  }
  .box{
    font-size:54px;
    background-color:white;
    color:#383838;
    margin-bottom:2.5%;
  }
  .landingbox i{
    font-size:200%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
  .landingbox{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:10%;
}

}

.landingbox{
  width:80%;
  font-size:40px;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
  color:#43B02a;
  margin-top:15%;
  margin-bottom:7.5%;
}

.landingbox i{
  color:#43B02a;
  margin-bottom:1.5%;
  margin-top:0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #383838;
  transition:0.3s;
}

.landingbox:hover i{
  margin-top:1.5%;
  margin-bottom:0;
  transition:0.3s;
}

section{
  width:100%;
  padding:7.5%;
  padding-left:15%;
  padding-right:0%;
  float:left;
}

.boxi{
  width:calc(70% / 3);
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  float:left;
  padding:2.5%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin-right:5%;
  text-align:center;
}
.boxi i{
  font-size:50px;
  color:#43B02a;
}

section h1{
  margin:0;
}

.eencontact{
  background-color:white;
  margin-right:5%;
  margin-top:4%;
  width:38%;
  float:left;
  font-size:20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.eencontact i{
  background-color:#43B02a;
  padding:3%;
  color:white;
  margin-right:3%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  section{
    padding:5%;

  }
  .boxi{
    width:100%;

    margin-bottom:5%;
  }
  #last{
    margin-right:0;
  }

  .eencontact{
    width:100%;

  }

  section h1{
  font-size:54px;
    font-weight:400;
   }
  h2{
    font-size:54px !important;
    font-weight:400;
  }
  h3{
    font-size:40px !important;
    font-weight:400;
  }

  a{
    font-size:36px !important;
  }
  p{
    font-size:36px !important;
  }
  .branche{
    font-size:36px !important;
    width:33.3% !important;
  }
  .branche i{
    font-size:50px !important;
  }
}


footer{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  color:white;
  background-color:#383838;
  padding:1%;
  padding-left:15%;
  padding-right:15%;
  padding-bottom:2%;
  color:white;

}

footer h3{
  margin-bottom:10px;
  color:#43B02a;
}

footer a{
  color:white;
}
footer i{
  color:white;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.footer_1-3{
  width: calc(80%/3);
  float:left;
  margin-right:10%;
  border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  footer{
    padding:5%;
  }
  .footer_1-3{
    width:40%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
    border-right:none;
    font-size:150%;
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }
}

.onepartner{
  float:left;
  width:15%;
  margin-right:1.5%;
}

.voordelen i{
  font-size:30px;
  color:#43B02a;
  margin-right:30px;
  width:50px;
  float:left;
}

.voordelen a{
  font-size:20px;
  color:#757575;
  width:80%;
  float:left;
  margin-top:20px;
}

#voordelenh1{
  margin-bottom:40px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .voordelen i{
  text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;


}

  .voordelen a{
  text-align:center;
    width:100%;

    margin-bottom:60px;

}
}

  #typcoach-left{
    width:65%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5%;
  }

#typcoach-right{
  width:15%;
  height:auto;
  float:left;
}

.samenwerking{
  float:left;
  width:40%;
  margin-right:2.5%;
  background-color:#f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  color:#757575;
}

.samenwerking p{
  margin:2.5%;
}

.samenwerking-top {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  margin-bottom:2.5%;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

.samenwerking-top h2{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  color:#43B02a;
  padding-left:5%;
}

.samenwerking-top img{
  float:right;
  width:auto;
  height:40px;
  margin-right:5%;
  margin-top:15px;

}

.voordelen2 i{
  font-size:15px;
  color:#43B02a;
  margin-right:30px;
  width:5%;
  float:left;
  margin-left:2.5%;
}

.voordelen2 a{
  font-size:15px;
  color:#757575;
  width:82.5%;
  float:left;
  margin-left:2.5%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
.samenwerking{
  width:100%;
  margin-right:0;
  margin-bottom:5%;
}

  .samenwerking-top h2{
    font-size:200%;
    font-weight:400;
}

  .voordelen2 i{
  font-size:30px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

  .samenwerking p{
  font-size:15px;
  width:95%;
}

.voordelen2 a{
  font-size:30px;
  width:95%;
  text-align:center;
}

}

footer i{
  font-size:30px;
}

.branche{
  width:calc(80%/3);
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:400;
  font-size:25px;
  margin-top:5%;
}

.branche i{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:40px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:0.3s;
  color:#43B02a;
}

.branche:hover i{
  font-size:50px;
  transition:0.3s;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  margin-top:-5px;
  color:#757575;
}

.arrowup{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:#43B02a;
  font-size:40px;
}

.arrowup i{
  color:#43B02a;
  font-size:40px;
  margin:5%;
  transition:0.3s;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.arrowup:hover i{
  margin-top:4.5%;
  margin-bottom:5.5%;
  transition:0.3s;
}
```

And for the html

```
 <!doctype html>

<html lang="nl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Brand name | Home</title>
  <meta name="description" content="
Een moderne typecursus voor professionals!">
  <meta name="author" content="Mikavdwiel.nl">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#43B02a" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="header-footer.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">



</head>


<body>
<header> 

  <div class="logo_container">
    <img src="img/logo (002).png">
  </div>
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="inschrijven.php" class="el">Inschrijven</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><bt>Over ons 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></bt>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="typcoach.html">Typcoach</a>
      <a href="samenwerkingen.html">Samenwerkingen</a>
      <a href="kwaliteitsbepalingen.html">Kwaliteitsbepalingen</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="contact.php" class="el">Contact</a>
  <a href="login.html" class="el" id="logbtn"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> <lg>Login</lg></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>
  <script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
</header>
  <landing>
  <div class="landing">
   <div class="typewriter">
   <h1>Leer op een effectieve manier in 5 uur blindtypen!</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="typewriter_mbl">
   <h1>Leer op een effectieve manier in 5 uur blindtypen!</h1>
   </div>

    <div class="landingbox">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
    </div>
    </div>
  </landing>


  <section>
    <div class="boxi">
      <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i><h2>
      Snel
      </h2><p>
      Binnen 5 uur kunnen blindtypen!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="boxi">
      <i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i><h2>
      Professioneel
      </h2><p>
      Een cursus speciaal voor profesionals!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="boxi" id="last">
      <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i><h2>
      Resultaat
      </h2><p>
      Meteen resultaat in uw bedrijfsvoering!
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section style="background-color:#f1f1f1;">
  <h1 id="responsivetexth1">
    Kunnen wij u helpen?
  </h1>
    <p><!--this paragraph is one of the elements that has the problem-->
      Heeft u vragen of wilt u zich graag inschrijven, neem dan nu contact met ons op.
    </p>
    <div class="eencontact">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> <a>Email@sdfsdf.nl</a>
    </div>
    <div class="eencontact">
    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i> <a>06 12345678</a>
    </div>
    <div class="eencontact">
    <i class="fas fa-headset"></i> <a>Contact formulier</a>
    </div>
    <div class="eencontact">
    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> <a>straat nr, stad</a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
  <h1>
    Bekijk wat bij u past
  </h1>
  <div class="branche">
    <i class="fas fa-medkit"></i>
  Zorginstellingen
  </div>
    <div class="branche">
      <i class="fas fa-building"></i>
   Bedrijven  
  </div>
    <div class="branche">
      <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>
  Onderwijsinstellingen  
  </div>
  </section>


  <section style="background-color:#f1f1f1;">
    <h1 id="voordelenh1">
      Wat zijn de voordelen?
    </h1>
    <div class="voordelen"><!--all of these a elements have the problem-->
    <a><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> Je leert blindtypen in 5 uur!</a>
    <a><i class="fas fa-smile"></i> Door een afname in de hoge werkdruk kunnen mensen meer ontspannen gaan werken. </a>
    <a><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Werktempo gaat omhoog, productiviteit neemt toe. </a>
    <a><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i> Gerichte aandacht op de inhoud van het werk in plaats van op het toetsenbord. </a>
    <a><i class="fas fa-comments"></i> Beter contact met uw gesprekspartner tijdens uw werkzaamheden. </a>
    <a><i class="fas fa-keyboard"></i> Typen met een afdekrekje, waardoor kijken onmogelijk is en u echt op uw vingers moet gaan vertrouwen. </a>
    <a><i class="fas fa-heartbeat"></i> Human4active bedrijfszorg & coaching informeert de cursisten over gezond werken. </a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="arrowup">
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
    </div>
  <footer>
  <div class="footer_1-3">
  <h3>
  Locatie  
  </h3>
    <a>
      Straat, nr<br>
      postcode plaats<br>
      Nederland
    </a><br>
    <h3>
  Social media 
  </h3>
    <a> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i> </a> <a> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> </a> <a> <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i> </a>
  </div>
    <div class="footer_1-3">
  <h3>
  Meer van ons 
  </h3>
    <a>sdfsdfsdfk</a><br>
    <a>Tdfsdfsdfn</a><br>
      <h3>
  Samenwerkingen en keurmerken
  </h3>
      <a>Husdfsdfive</a><br>
    <a>Btfsdfys</a><br>
  </div>
    <div class="footer_1-3" style="margin-right:0;">
  <h3>
  Over ons 
  </h3>
    <a>Typcoach</a><br>
    <a>voorwaarden & privacybeleid</a><br>
    <a>Kwaliteitsbepalingen</a><br>
    <a>Keurmerken</a><br>
      <h3>
  Contact
  </h3>
      <a>Hfdsdfive</a><br>
    <a>Btsddfsdfys</a><br>
  </div>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I allso put it on codepen:
https://codepen.io/Mika_vd_wiel/pen/JQOeYb

Comment: It should be easy to find the source if you just inspect the offending tag to see where the font size is getting set. Right click on element, inspect

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. [mcve]

Comment: @Huangism i did, and it only shows the one size i want it to be but it is the wrong size, when i edit it via inspect element it does work correctly but when i change it via the css file it doesn't

Comment: On mobile it is 36px as you have set with important, is this not correct?

Comment: @Huangism, when you view it on mobile, two parts dont change to the desired 36 px, now it changes them to 49.2 px

Comment: Which one didn't change? the problematic p tag and the anchors tags are all at 36. Be more specific, give me a sample text to search for

Comment: @Huangism The paragraph at the section with the h1 of"waarmee kunnen wij u helpen" and all the anchor tags at "wat zijn de voordelen"

Comment: Note: you MUST post your code **within the question** and NOT any third party site!

Comment: @Rob its an entire webpage, isn't that a little bit too large?

Comment: @Huangism, now i sse it too, it changes correctly on codepen but on my phone or pc (chrome) they don't

Comment: As the link I gave you stated: you must post a **minimal reproducible example**. If you can't do that, then you must go elsewhere for this.

Comment: You forgot the **minimal** part.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see you code I can see you have several large font declarations:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px)
    h2 {
        font-size: 54px !important;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px)
    .typewriter_mbl {
        margin: 5%;
        font-size: 46px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px)
    section h1 {
        font-size: 54px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
}
```

They go from small to very large.

Your body declaration should include a font-size to set a base size.

Additionally you are using H1 and H2 without removing their default values which makes them somewhat unpredictable. Try using span or div instead to better control for that. Or you could use normalize css to remove the default values.

This isn't a quick fix. Good luck!